# mod_rewrite conflicts with Alias directive

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

My primary web site uses PHP/Zend Framework, and the .htaccess is the common one:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Now I need to bring a forum (in another directory) to the main site. I added an Alias directive inside VirtualHost

```
Alias /forums "h:/projects/forums"
```

The forum software uses its own .htaccess. The main URL /forums is accessible but not others. Other URLs (those who do not have corresponding files) are forwarded to the main site. In other words, the .htaccess file of the main site (/) is picked up, not the one under /forums directory.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a new `RewriteCond` to tell your main `.htaccess` file to ignore requests under `/forums`. After the request passes through that file, it should get picked up by the `/forums/.htaccess` file, though I'll admit that I'm not really sure if `Alias` affects this.

The condition would look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forums [NC]
```

This says "only perform the next `RewriteRule` if the request doesn't begin with `/forums`". The `[NC]` at the end says to ignore the casing on `/forums` so it won't matter if the request is actually for `/Forums` or `/FORUMS`.